# Определение темы для wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть следующая тема с добавленным к ней логотипом DigitalElectronics

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на админ панели WordPress-а узнать какая тема была использована на сайте?

Comment: Посмотреть в файл стилей. Только это скорее всего не поможет. Там наверняка переписаны заголовки.

Answer (score 1):

Если верить строчке в футере, то это тема , построенная на основе [стартовой темы Underscores](https://underscores.me).

Больше вы скорее всего не узнаете, да и зачем?
Видно,что это стартовая тема, сгенерированная на сайте с минимальными изменениями.

Answer (score 0):

Узнать активную тему: Админ панель - Внешний вид - Темы